# Read & write shapefiles in android or java (.shp)

Tags: android, gis, shapefile

Read & Write shapefiles in android or java

How can i read and write **shapefiles** in Android or java?

> .shp .shx and etc

i much searched but nothing

I want read file and edit information and write in same file or new file.

This is important i can write to file. i can read file but this isn't my problem

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take **Gdal for Android** for a try.

- [Gdal](https://gdal.org/)

A translator library for raster and vector geospatial data formats that is released under an X/MIT style Open Source license by the Open Source Geospatial Foundation. As a library, it presents a single raster abstract data model and single vector abstract data model to the calling application for all supported formats. It also comes with a variety of useful command line utilities for data translation and processing. The NEWS page describes the January 2017 GDAL/OGR 2.1.3 release.

- [Read/Write API Tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/vector_api_tut.html)
- [Building for Android on Linux](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid)
- Either, Google for pre-compiled package

Comment: @YasharPanahi Did you managed to get GDAL working? When I try `Driver driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");` it returns null. I can't seem to get drivers to work.

Comment: @WhizBoy I hadn't problem

Comment: @YasharPanahi Maybe you could share .aar file if you still have it? I was told there could be some compile-options problems but I cant seem to get it right then. Everything else works except Drivers.